# implementing inertial delay in multiple ways

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to implement inertial delay in SystemVerilog to generate a signal `valid_inputs` with following criterion
1. `valid_inputs` should go to '1' after some delay (say 15 units) if no inputs are X/Z
2. `valid_inputs` should go to '0' immediately if atleast one input becomes X/Z.

I am trying the above with 2 implementations:

```
module test (a, b, y);

    input a, b;
    output y;

    wire temp;
    assign temp = ^{a,b};
    bit valid_inputs_temp, valid_inputs_2;
    wire valid_inputs;

    always @(temp)
    begin
        if (temp === 1'b1 || temp === 1'b0)
        begin
            valid_inputs_temp <= 1'b1;
        end
        else
        begin
            valid_inputs_temp <= 1'b0;
        end
    end
    assign #(15,0) valid_inputs = valid_inputs_temp;

    always @(temp)
    begin
        if (temp === 1'b1 || temp === 1'b0)
        begin
            #15 valid_inputs_2 <= 1'b1;
        end
        else
        begin
            valid_inputs_2 <= 1'b0;
        end
    end

endmodule
```

While the signal `valid_inputs` works perfectly, but I'm not quite sure why `valid_inputs_2` doesn't work exactly the same? Is there a way I can implement the inertial delay using `always`-`begin` procedural code?

Please note that while I could modify the `assign` statement in the above code such that I totally eliminate the corresponding `always`-`begin` block, for some reason I need to use the `always`-`begin` style of coding.

Thanks,
Vinayak

Comment: what is the reason for using min/max expression in the delay? instead of `#(15,0)` you can use just `#15`. It should bring you closer tot he second implementation. Also, do **not** use non-blocking assighments in these blocks use `=` instead of '`<=`. it is not vhdl.  And in the first case you have delay imposed for both '1' and '0', thought in the second case only '1' is delayed. Add #15 to the second clause as well.

Comment: @Serge `#(15,0)` is rise,fall, not min::max

Comment: @dave_59 thanks, did no use those for a long while :-(. I'm taking my suggestion about delays back.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second `always` block does not work is that you have a blocking `#15` delay. That suspends the always process and misses a change on `temp` if it occurs in less that 15 time units. You need to move the delay to the other side of the `<=` so it becomes a non-blocking assignment delay.

```
    valid_inputs_2 <= #15 1'b1;
```

And if you are confused about how an `always` block executes, see [this link.](http://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?t=332596&p=1419672&viewfull=1#post1419672)

Comment: If `temp` is valid for less than 15 time units, the two methods will behave differently.

Comment: @dave_59 Would an intra-assignment delay make it a transport delay rather than inertial? I'm not sure if I understand well, but to implement inertial delay, I'm trying to do a delayed evaluation. Please help me understand if I'm wrong.

Comment: No. Intra-assignment delay in a blocking assignment creates the same problem within an `always` block - it suspends the block and will not see changes on signals while blocked

Comment: @dave_59 Sorry, in my previous comment, I meant to suggest if intra-assignment delay in a NBA would make it transport delay rather than inertial. Further, I do not know if intra-assignment delay in a blocking statement is of any good use (Does it represent any hardware behaviour at all?) However, I need to implement inertial delay using procedural code.

Comment: Why must it be procedural?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good example of inertial delay. The reason is that any 0->1 or 1->0 transition makes the output as 1. So pulses do not logically cause any difference in the output.

So there is no way to distinguish it from transport delay.

Moreover, the output turns 0 immediately for z. So there is no delay in that either.
Hence the signal "valid_inputs_2" is transport delay (<= #15).

To my knowledge there is no way to create inertial delay using always block.